# Disable item after 10 shots

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I disable an object after you press 10 times the left mouse button? This is the script that I'm using, but does not work very well.

```
#pragma strict

var myTrigger : GameObject;
var myObject : GameObject;
var countAmmo : int = 10 ;

function Start()
{
}

function Update()
{
  if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))

     countAmmo = 10;

        //myObject.SetActive(true);

        countAmmo = (countAmmo -1);

         countAmmo = 0; 

        myObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: This script is in unity.

Comment: each time you trigger the Input.GetButtonDown if you reset the countAmmo value to 10. Try moving counAmmo = 10 outside. In the if loop you should only remove one item from countAmmo and check if the variable is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow proper variable scopes..
try this:

```
    var countAmmo : int = 10 ;

    function Update()
     {

      if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))  

         countAmmo = countAmmo -1;        
         if(countAmmo == 0){         
            myObject.SetActive(false);    
         }else{
            myObject.SetActive(true);
         } 
     }
}
```

I believe you're trying to reduce the count by one in each button press, until the count is zero . and if no more ammo(count = 0), you need to disable the fire button, right?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. I would also add the count with GUIText on the screen as I add it? I'm working on a 2d game.
thank you

Comment: add in this script guitext to see the numbers from 10 to 0 scroll across the screen. Adding GuiText the script properly.

example.

  var countAmmo: int = 10;

     Update () function
      {

       if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1"))

          countAmmo countAmmo = -1;
          if (countAmmo == 0) {
             myObject.SetActive (false);
          } Else {
             myObject.SetActive (true);
          }
      }
}

OnGui function ()

GUI.Label (New Rect (screen.width / 2 - x Screen / 2 screen.height / 2 - ZScreen / 2 x Screen, ZScreen));
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your logic in an `if`.

```
countAmmo = countAmmo - 1;
if (countAmmo <= 10){
    myObject.SetActive(true);
} else {
    myObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you cosx this works, but when it comes to 0 does not turn off the subject, continues to be active.

Answer (score 0):

First try remove both `countAmmo=10;` and `countAmmo=0;` from inside the event itself. And change the function like this:

```
 if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && (countAmmo >0))  

     countAmmo -= 1;

     if(countAmmo == 0){         
        myObject.SetActive(false);    
     }else{
        myObject.SetActive(true);
     } 
 }
```